# Rails function to get "hours, minutes, seconds" until timestamp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, time

Have been digging around the docs but cannot find if there is a function to calculate the

- hours
- minutes
- seconds

As separate vars from a ruby date time stamp

Is there a build in function or does one have to calculate it by himself?

Comment: Did you mean "until" (a duration) or just a timestamp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html), check out `distance_of_time_in_words`, I think that is what you are looking for.

For instance:

```
def find_time
  distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, due_at)
end
```

This will calculate the length of time from now until the timestamp of `due_at`. You can pass the option `include_seconds = true` to display seconds as well.

Comment: Great this is What I was looking for indeed, only 1 small problem it says " about 3 hours " is there a way to remove that "about" text from the function ? Or do i Need to change the locales for that. I would like to change "about" to "around" thx!

Comment: The easiest way probably would be to override it in the locales file.